# SQL multiple join query

Tags: sql, join

I have this SQL query, and directly under it, another query based on the result.
I'd like to merge them, but im getting confused, being a newbie.

It's pulling data from 3 tables- the first query from the USERS and the PLAYERS table. Then if the player is in a 'team', it gets the tag from the TEAMS table.

My code:

```
$sql_result4=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users JOIN players ON users.player=players.name WHERE users.id='$id'"); 
$rs4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result4); 

if ($rs4[team] !=0) {
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT tag FROM teams WHERE id='$rs4[team]'", $db); 
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result);
    // get data
}
```

My question is, how could i merge that second query in with the first? Am I even using the right kind of join?

I want to be able to use lots of data from the PLAYERS table, but only one or two columns from the USERS and TEAMS ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a left join.

```
SELECT ... 
FROM users u 
    JOIN players p ON u.player = p.name
    LEFT JOIN teams t ON p.team = t.id
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Comment: Could you update it to specify how i pick which fields i pull from each table? thanks :D

Comment: In the SELECT, you can have users.* (to get all from users table), players.name, players.skill (to only get player name and skill) and then team.tag (to only get tag from the team table).

So, what you have is SELECT users.*, player.name, player.skill, team.tag FROM ...

Comment: Yeah I tried that before but had errors, lemme try again... yeah, error. Says not a valid result resource.

Comment: Wait I've worked it. I had to use SELECT u.* instead of users.*

Comment: In general, you should be explicitly specifying the fields that you want to retrieve. The use of `SELECT *` is fragile and can break your app when the schema changes.